# Facebook Insights API for web site

Tags: facebook, metrics, facebook-insights

This questions gets asked a lot but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

What I want to do : Receive metrics and data of one of my web sites from Facebook insight via there API.
What I did so far : The meta tag and everything is in place. I have read the docs. I can see some simple metrics on the insight dashboard like shares.

According to the Facebook docs their API is available for pages, apps and domains. It works very well when ever I try to get data from an app (https://graph.facebook.com/324923697601554/insights) but every time I try that exact same thing with my domain id (given by the meta tag), all I get is an empty page that looks like this:

```
:{
    "data": [
      
   ],
   "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/415793855145069/insights?access_token=...&since=1349198931&until=1349458131",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/415793855145069/insights?access_token=...&since=1349717331&until=1349976531"
   }
}
```

I have already read the Facebook docs but I can't figure the problem out.

Comment: Have you allowed your app with insights permissions?

Comment: @SIR Thanks for your reply, but my problem is not getting data from an app, but from a domain. As far as I know I can't allow such permissions for a domain. If you are talking about the read_insight permissions, they give me access to the users insight, and I only need mine, so I don't have to request that.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem? Slightly different set up (the domain is linked to an app id set up just for domain insights) but same issue. Played around and even used a app access token requested with scope=read_insights (which gave me a token but did not give me any luck with the data)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried '&access_token'?

More information on access tokens:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/